# Python: How to join an operator?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-i18n, django-filters

I'm currently developing a Django application with i18n support.
This works by providing a field for each language for a given field.

Example model:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    title_en = models.CharField()
    title_de = models.CharField()
    title_fr = models.CharField()

    # etc...
```

(under the hood this is automatically done using [django-translated-fields](https://pypi.org/project/django-translated-fields/))

I would now like to filter for `Article`s with a given `title`. The `title` should be checked in every available language. (so in this case `title_en`, `title_de` and `title_fr`).

If there was only one `title`, I could query like this:

```py
Article.objects.filter(title=my_title)
```

I don't want to use this:

```py
Article.objects.filter(Q(title_en=my_title) | Q(title_de=my_title) | Q(title_fr=my_title))
```

since the fields are created dynamically and the available languages could change.

## My question

I need to somehow join classes using the `__union__` operator.

I came up with this:

```py
Article.objects.filter(*[
    Q(**{
        f"name_{code}": my_name
    })
    for code in available_languages
])
```

but the joining is missing.

Is there any method to do this? Or is there a better method available to filter for the names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a list of available languages, you can work with:

```
available_languages = ['en', 'de', 'fr']

q_filter = Q(
    *[Q((f'title_{code}', my_title)) for code in available_languages],
    _connector=Q.OR
)

Article.objects.filter(q_filter)
```

Comment: I didn't know about `_connector`! Sometimes it's a good idea to take a look at the source code ;)